# How to stop reformatting of intelliJ after save

Tags: intellij-idea, reformatting

This is a simple question that I can't find an answer. I'm using IntelliJ for Java practice.

I have blocks of code that are just a single line, followed by an end brace, like this,

```
public void example(){
    System.out.println("Some string");
}
```

Edit: After saving and closing the app, then reopen the project, IntelliJ reformats this as

```
public void example(){ System.out.println("Some string"); }
```

How do I stop IntelliJ from doing this? It becomes a hassle when I need to add more things into the block, I need to click it to expand the block. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not reformat, it is a [folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html) feature. Please disable the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Code Folding | **One-line methods** option.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not IntelliJ's standard behaviour, I assume you might have [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin installed.

If this is the case, check its options (Settings -> Save Actions -> Formatting actions).

Comment: It's a fresh install, I only have EduTools. By the way, when I meant after saving, I meant that when I save and close the application, and reopen it, then it reformats.